# cgconfig.conf : setting root control group parameters

Tags: linux

I've got cpu, cpuacct and memory cgroups configured via /etc/cgconfig.conf ( cgconfig-bin on Lucid ). I can add new control groups, and assign processes to them however there does not seem to be a facility for changing the paramters of the root level memory cgroup ( the actual mount point ).

How would one best set such parameters in a clean manner withoput c

For example, I've the memory cgroup mounted to /var/run/cgroup/memory. 
I'd like to have /var/run/cgroup/memory/memory.use_hierarchy set to 1 on boot.

Comment: Just as I'd gotten annoyed and decided to ask for help, I found the answer .. go figure. The root control group is referenced by a standard group <name> { } statement where <name> is a single period.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment to the question

The root control group is referenced by a standard group `<name> { }` statement where `<name>` is a single period.

Answer (score -1):

What is the point in limiting the root group? You're basically limiting all tasks that are running on the system. And secondly, there are some drawbacks when altering the parameters of a root group, see:

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html-single/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html#process_behavior

Some parameters even can't be set for a root group, e.g. `memory.limit_in_bytes`. From the doc above:

> You cannot use memory.limit_in_bytes to limit the root cgroup; you can only apply values to groups lower in the hierarchy.